# react-router-dom v6 history push and useNavigate problem

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom, mobx

I'am using react-router-dom v6 and mobex in my project and get an error when I use it as below.

main.tsx:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import App from './app/layout/App'
import './app/layout/styles.css'
import 'semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css'
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.min.css'
import 'react-calendar/dist/Calendar.css'
import 'react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css'
import { store, StoreContext } from './app/stores/store'
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
export const navigate = useNavigate();

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')!).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <StoreContext.Provider value={store}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <App />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </StoreContext.Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
)
```

userStore.ts:

```
import { UserFormValues } from './../models/user';
import { makeAutoObservable, runInAction } from "mobx";
import { User } from "../models/user";
import agent from '../api/agent';
import { store } from './store';
import { navigate } from '../../main';

export default class UserStore {
    user:User | null = null;

    constructor() {
        makeAutoObservable(this);
    }

    logout = () => {
        store.commonStore.setToken(null);
        window.localStorage.removeItem('jwt');
        this.user = null;
        navigate('/');
    }
}
```

Error:

```
"Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component"
```

In the old version it was working when I did it like this below:

main.tsx:

```
...
...
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";
export const history = createBrowserHistory();
...
...
```

and userStore.tsx:

```
import { makeAutoObservable, runInAction } from "mobx";
import agent from "../api/agent";
import { User, UserFormValues } from "../models/user";
import { store } from "./store";
import { history } from "../../index";

export default class UserStore {
  user: User | null = null;

  constructor() {
    makeAutoObservable(this);
  }

  logout = () => {
    store.commonStore.setToken(null);
    window.localStorage.removeItem("jwt");
    this.user = null;
    history.push("/");
  };
```

How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line `const navigate = useNavigate()` can only be inside a React component or custom hook, as `useNavigate` is a hook. See [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html) to know more. One way to solve this is to change your `logout` function, so it takes `navigate` as a parameter, like so:

```
logout = (navigate) => {
  store.commonStore.setToken(null);
  window.localStorage.removeItem("jwt");
  this.user = null;
  navigate("/");
};
```

And call `useNavigate` in the component where you call `logout` and give `navigate` to it as a parameter. Like so as an example:

```
import UserStore from "./UserStore"; // use the correct path
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

export default function Component() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const userStore = UserStore();
  userStore.logout(navigate);

  return <div></div>;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Issue

React hooks can only be used within a React function component and the `useNavigate` hook can only be used within a routing context.

## Solution

Access the `navigate` function via the `useNavigate` hook from a React function component and pass a reference to `navigate` to the `logout` handler.

```
logout = ({ navigate }) => {
  store.commonStore.setToken(null);
  window.localStorage.removeItem("jwt");
  this.user = null;
  navigate("/");
};
```

...

```
const SomeComponent = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  ...
  UserStore.logout({ navigate });
  ...
};
```

## Alternative Solution

Import and use the [`HistoryRouter`](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/routers/history-router) and continue using the custom `history` object as previously. This requires `history@5` package dependency, install it if necessary (*run `npm i -S history@5`*).

Example:

Create and export `history` object.

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";
export const history = createBrowserHistory();
```

...

```
...
import { unstable_HistoryRouter as HistoryRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { history } from '../path/to/history';

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')!).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <StoreContext.Provider value={store}>
      <HistoryRouter history={history}>
        <App />
      </HistoryRouter>
    </StoreContext.Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

UserStore continues to import the `history` object and use it.

```
import { makeAutoObservable, runInAction } from "mobx";
import agent from "../api/agent";
import { User, UserFormValues } from "../models/user";
import { store } from "./store";
import { history } from "../path/to/history";

export default class UserStore {
  user: User | null = null;

  constructor() {
    makeAutoObservable(this);
  }

  logout = () => {
    store.commonStore.setToken(null);
    window.localStorage.removeItem("jwt");
    this.user = null;
    history.push("/");
  };

  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use hooks in class component.
for route trough class component there is another way to do that.
but I think in router 6 class component support is dropped.
so you can change your class component to function component it is easy way.